# Fix the size of 'html' and 'body' elements to be exactly those of the screen

Tags: html, css, flexbox, height

I often need that `html` and `body` elements have the size of the screen. Typically, in the case when I want to have a `svg` element fit the whole screen.

To achieve that, I saw that it was possible to use CSS code as follow.

```css
html,body{margin:0;padding:0;height:100%;}
```

The code that I personnaly use is the following one.

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
}

body {
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Both seem to work well, but I recently had the following remark.

> `html { height: 100%; display: flex; }` is a useless declaration. html height will always be calculated to fit content. Also `100%` means 100% of the parent. `html` has no parent... also applying flexbox to `html` is useless as it only has 1 child element that is visible: `body`.

Actually:

- I put `100%` of `html` height in order to have it fit the screen height.
- I apply flexbox to `html` in order to be able to use `flex-glow: 1` on its child, and have this child filling its parent.

Is there any better to solution than mine?

Comment: Either solution is fine. That "remark" is plain wrong on all counts.

Comment: Interesting discussion on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593106/styling-the-html-element-in-css

Answer (score 1):

I personally use this:

```css
html {
  display: grid;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

This will make your body full height by default and will also respect default margin

```css
html {
  display: grid;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: blue;
}

body {
  background: red;
}
```

And you can easily use `height:100%` on an inner element without issue:

```css
html {
  display: grid;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: blue;
}

body {
  background: red;
}

.box {
  height: 100%;
  border: 5px solid green;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I find that whenever working with elements that need to be the full height of the screen `height: 100vh` is usually a good place to start. VH = viewport height. I use it over height: 100% as depending on the layout 100% doesn't always equal the page height, so with VH you know exactly what you are getting!

With VH you can also then use a calc() in your CSS, so if you needed your body to fill the whole height of the page, but subtract the height of a header for example you could do something like this:

```
<header style="height: 64px">
<section style="height: calc(100vh - 64px)"
```